# stepEnter or canEnter at step in wizard doesn't work in Archwizard Angular 9

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, wizard

I try to use angular Archwizard (last version) in my app , it works fine but when i'm trynig to do some controls about variable that i send from step 1 to step 2, and in step 2 the work that it will do depends on this variable, i work with [canEnter] and also (stepEnter) but it seems doesn't work with me , here the link in slackbitz to what i'm trying doing  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ps1k5n?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html&view=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have data type handling issue, in your `first-step.component`

This html area

```
  <option  value="true"> True </option>
  <option value="false"> False</option>
```

And your TS

```
 saveFlag() {
    this.status = this.firstForm.controls['type'].value; // this one returns a string;
    this.sendFlag.emit(this.status);
  }
```

> Hence, your status is string not a boolean

So in your `app.component` do it like this instead

```
  getRequestStatus ($event){
    this.status = $event === 'true';
    this.finishedStep1 = true;
  }
```

There are couple of solution about this, but this is the easiest part.